# High CPU load of executable with Python thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I use the following python-code to execute a C-program (executable):

```
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=10)
thread = Thread(target=streamstdout, args=(proc.stdout, conn))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    conn.settimeout(0.01)
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        continue
    except socket.error:
        print 'Connection break during execution.'
        if proc.poll() == None: 
            proc.terminate()
            print 'Execution terminated'
        break
    data = data.strip()
    if data: print 'Received: ', data
```

The conn is a TCP-connection.
Everything is right when I start the python script in my console with

```
python script.py
```

The CPU-load of the executable is around 30% as expected.

But if I start the python-script at boot-time in crontab or I start the script with

```
nohup python script.py &
```

and suppress with this call the output-messages of the python-script, the executable runs always with the maximum CPU-load (98%-100%).
I think the problem is the output of the python-script which can not outputted on the console...but why happens this?

I'm grateful for every idea or opinion.

Update: I appended the while-loop. But I don't think this is relevant for the problem.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Add more debugging to your script so you can figure out which loop you spend a lot of time in.

Comment: @nos: the problematic CPU-load is the one of the executable, not the CPU-Load of the python-script. But I appended more python-code in my post.

Comment: Has nobody an idea :(?